# HomeKit : Error enabling notification on characteristic

Tags: ios, homekit, ios-homekit

I am currently working on homekit app, lets say "MyThermoApp". When making local command updates to the thermostat i.e both MyThermoApp and thermostat being in same local wifi, everything works fine but the issue arises when "MyThermoApp" updates the thermostat temperature in remote mode.

I have MyThermoApp running in two devices. Let's say both are remote. When I make update using ThermoApp in device A the temperature is update in thermostat but the update is not displayed correctly in another MyThermoApp running in device B.

I get the error :  **HomeKit : Error enabling notification on characteristic** with localizedDescription **Accessory is not reachable** which is not true because the accessory is available and on.

Can somebody please guide me through the issue? Thank you